# puppet service not stopping service

Tags: iptables, puppet, service

```
notice ("This should be echoed")
service { "iptables":
    ensure => "stopped",
}
```

This does not stop iptables, I am not sure why.  `service iptables stop` works fine.  Puppet 2.6.17 on CentOS 6.3.

UPDATE:
**/etc/puppet/manifests/nodes.pp**

```
 node 'linux-dev' {
    include mycompany::install::apache::init
    include mycompany::config::services::init
}
```

**/etc/puppet/modules/mycompany/manifests/config/services/init.pp**

```
class mycompany::config::services::init {
    if ($::id == "root") {
        service { 'iptables':
        #name => '/sbin/iptables',
        #enable => false,
        #hasstatus => true,
        ensure => stopped
    } 
    notice ("IPTABLES is now being stopped...")

    file { '/tmp/puppet_still_works':
        ensure => 'present',
        owner => root

    } else {
    err("Error: this manifest must be run as the root user!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is different for iptables since there is no daemon, it is not like for crond daemon for example. Service type will look in the process table for a process name "iptables" and if it is not there it will assume it is stopped. Add 'hasstatus => true' and it will work. 
EDITED:
status => "true", worked this usually supplies for type service manually, this command must return 0 if the service is running and a nonzero value otherwise.

```
notice ("This should be echoed")
service { "iptables":
    ensure => "stopped",
    hasstatus => "true",
    status => "true",
```

}

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work still.  The status command does exist for service iptables, but this manifest does not stop the service strangely, even after adding hasstatus => true.  As a side note, should true/false values be quoted?  Wouldn't that "stringify" a boolean operator?  I was wondering about that as well.

Comment: I do not have it quoted, I think it is unnecessary. I would get rid of them. also it does not make difference but i would do 'iptables', also do you have "service iptables status' on your OS, there isn't on some OS's

Comment: Yes, like I said above: "The status command does exist for service iptables".  I even tried:    exec { 'service iptables stop':
        path => '/sbin',
        unless => "service iptables status"
    }
but it still didnt work.

Comment: try onlyif instead of unless, also this just worked for me in vagrant puppet apply -e "service{'iptables': ensure => stopped}" rhel6.4 Something weird.

Comment: Also, service type has a 'stop' parameter to specify a stop command, instead of using the exec

Comment: puppet apply -e "service{'iptables': ensure => stopped}" works for me too.

Comment: See my updates, perhaps I have something wrong in my general config?  However, the /tmp/puppet_still_works file does get created.

Comment: Do not see any issue, what OS ?

Comment: CentOS 6.3 on clients and puppet server

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Does it work for any other service? Like apache or crond?

Comment: I added an httpd ensure => stopped and it works.  Also it gave the notice httpd changed from running to stopped, I never got notices about the iptables, it simply skips the whole block it seems.

Comment: Then I commented out the original IPtables block and just changes the working httpd block to iptables but it did nothing.  I guess there is a problem with the init script?

Comment: I noticed the init script for iptables is /bin/sh but httpd is /bin/bash, testing that now.  Nope, didn't seem to matter anything.

Comment: can you also try to add: status => "true",

Comment: or status => '/sbin/service iptables status | grep "is not running"', try these ...

Comment: YES!!!! Adding status => "true" resolved it!!

Comment: Ok, Glad it worked for you. Still do not get it why it doesn't work with just stopped, as it works for 6.4. Must be different init scripts.